# How to set image and text right top of relative layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
 <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/nameText"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:ems="10"
               android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
               android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
               android:text="Ajay Kulkarni"
               android:textColor="#3e4360"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:textStyle="normal"/>
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
               android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
               android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
               android:text="Co-Founder"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:textColor="@color/bluey_grey_three"
               android:textSize="12sp"
               android:textStyle="normal"/>

           <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

               android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
               android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
               android:background="@drawable/ic_success_illustration" />

           <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
               android:layout_width="64dp"
               android:layout_height="64dp"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
               android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
               android:background="@drawable/ic_cards_active"
               android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

           <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
               android:layout_width="64dp"
               android:layout_height="64dp"
               android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
               android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
               android:background="@drawable/ic_cards_active"
               android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
       </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml i want set  all 2 textview  2 imageview right  of relative layout in android .  my expected screen is like below please suggest me how i will set  textview and imageview in right top in relative layout .
[image]

using given code i am able keep one imageview right side i have keep  both textview right and one imageview also .

Comment: where is your expected screen?

Comment: the given solution by @iamgopal is correct but one more imageview  we have to display left of given imageview that i am unable to set

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Cheers.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
        android:text="Ajay Kulkarni"
        android:textColor="#3e4360"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageView3"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
        android:text="Co-Founder"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

           android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
           android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_success_illustration" />

       <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
           android:layout_width="64dp"
           android:layout_height="64dp"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_cards_active"
           android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

       <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
           android:layout_width="64dp"
           android:layout_height="64dp"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
           android:background="@drawable/ic_cards_active"
           android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Check here]

Comment: but we have two image view its overlapping i need septate it like i punted circular u can see in expected screen,

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

          <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".1">



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                    android:text="Ajay Kulkarni"
                    android:textColor="#3e4360"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                    android:text="Co-Founder"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

            </RelativeLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imgone"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera_white_48dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/imagetow"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_camera_white_48dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>


    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: thanx but check my expected output   is correct only we want to right side text and image view but in given solution its coming left side textview

Comment: no dear the given solution by  imgopal is correct i need to add one more image view left of or right of first image view

Comment: @ManojKumar  you mean to say like  **Imageview>Textview>ImageView** or post your exact screen i correct it

Comment: @ManojKumar As you mansion **expectedoutput** One Textview Rightside two Imageview...so i have done based on your expectedOUtput